# Django unable to find page

Tags: python, django

For some reason, Django is not picking up a certain template and I am unsure why.

**Link in navbar.html**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/course/posts/{{ course.slug }}">{{ course.title }}</a>
```

**views.py**

```
def posts(request, course_slug, *args, **kwargs):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(course__id=course.id)
    courses = Course.objects.all()

    context = {
        'posts' : posts,
        'courses' : courses,
    }

    return render(request, "course/posts.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
from . import admin_views

app_name = 'course'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<course_slug>\w+)$', views.posts, name='posts'),
    url(r'^admin/course/create$', admin_views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^admin/course/update/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)$', admin_views.update, name='update')
]
```

Comment: does it return template not found?

Comment: Returned "Page not found (404)"

Comment: could you please post the full traceback error

Comment: Have you registered your template? Are you referring to it properly?

Comment: Added full error. It's simply a Page not found. I'm confused mainly because I used a similar strategy for the `update` url and I did not meet an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change href in navbar.html

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'course:posts' %}">{{ course.title }}</a>
```

Comment: this basically is the same as above logic wise

Comment: idk ask the OP :D

Comment: I'd still like to reference the `course.slug` in my href so that it passes to my URL so I can't use this solution either way.